# Django : ImportError ; No module named urls

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm a complete beginner in Django and I try without success to create my first django web page with just 'Hello world' on it. I've been trying for a few hours to solve my problem by looking on the internet but none of the solutions worked for me. Here is my code : I hope I can get help here...

Here is my directory tree :

./ProjetArbre:
AppliPageArbre  arbre.db  **init**.py  manage.py  ProjetArbre

./ProjetArbre/AppliPageArbre:
admin.py   **init**.py   models.py   tests.py  views.py
admin.pyc  **init**.pyc  models.pyc  urls.py

./ProjetArbre/ProjetArbre:
**init**.py   settings.py   urls.py   wsgi.py
**init**.pyc  settings.pyc  urls.pyc  wsgi.pyc

Here is ProjetArbre/AppliPageArbre/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns,url
from views import home

urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$',home,name="home")
)
```

ProjetArbre/AppliPageArbre/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request) :
    #return HttpResponse("HelloWorld")
    print 'HelloWorld'
```

ProjetArbre/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ProjetArbre.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^AppliPageArbre/', include('ProjetArbre.AppliPageArbre.urls')),
)
```

And finally ProjetArbre/ProjetArbre/settings.py :

```
""" Django settings for ProjetArbre project.

For more information on this file, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/ """

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...) import os BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! SECRET_KEY = 'v%!t3(w*fr)0n_!98=se_o_+@+o2(_0*d0&pu19@z5g1hxz13^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'AppliPageArbre', )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls' #simplement urls ?

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProjetArbre.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'arbre.db'),
    } }

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The error I get on http://localhost:8000/AppliPageArbre/home is :

```
ImportError at /AppliPageArbre/home

No module named urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/AppliPageArbre/home
Django Version:     1.6
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named urls

Exception Location:     /home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/eisti/Dev/ProjetArbre',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/eisti/Dev/Environnement/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    jeu, 19 Jan 2017 18:29:34 +0100
```

I'm using Django 1.6
Thank you in advance for your help...

Comment: Since you've just started using django you should use a supported version of it, there are multiple duplicates around for this specific error, what happened when you tried their solutions?

Comment: Why are  you using Django 1.6 when latest is 1.10?

Comment: I got the same error or other errors. I've tried to install different versions of django,  to add " ' " at different places, to change some paths with the name of my project or not... I didn't find any solution that worked for me. I use 1.6 because the book I learn from is old, and their code don't work with django 1.10

Comment: 1.6 is very outdated and no longer supported version, you should use the latest version as it has more features,lesser bugs and easier to use so less of a pain and also will get more help and materials on the internet.

Comment: You'll find that you are pigeon holing yourself by using 1.6 to learn with since there was a HUGE change with what django uses for its database ORM between 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: The settings should have `ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProjetArbre.urls'`. Please find another book or tutorial that supports at least Django 1.8. Otherwise you'll hit lots of problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProjetArbre.urls' doesn't work and shows approximately the same error. I'm trying to do it on Django 1.10 !

Answer (score -1):

I manage to solve this problem by reading another tutorial on Django 1.10. Thanks :)

Now, I have another problem : in models.py, I have the following classes for example :

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    sexe = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=genre_choix,default="N")
    id_profil = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False)
    famille = models.ForeignKey(Famille, default=0, blank=True,unique=False,null=True)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    prenom2 = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    nom_famille = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nom_jeune_fille = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    Date_anniv = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    mort = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    travail = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="", blank=True)
    information = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    profil_picture = models.FileField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prenom)



class Couple(models.Model):
    p1 = models.ForeignKey("Profil", related_name='+')
    p2 = models.ForeignKey("Profil", related_name='+')
    marriage = models.DateField(default="", blank=True,null=True)
    divorce = models.DateField(default="", blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.p1.prenom+"<3"+self.p2.prenom)
```

And I'd like that each time I create a new Profil, a Couple is created with p1 = the Profil I just created and p2 = a false profile with "?" instead of the name. However I have no idea of how to do that because of the two Foreign Keys...

Comment: You should *never* do this, don't update your answer and just say "thanks, I figured it out", because other people who search for the problem will not find an answer. explain how you did it. Also, do not answer your own question with another totally different question.